# Setting Java Version on Ubuntu to Java 7?

Tags: ubuntu, java

I have downloaded Open JDK 7 and installed it.

I can see the location as:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

How can I now use Java 7 as my java version on my Ubuntu VM rather than Open `JDK 6` that I have currently installed?

Answer (score 0):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

then check

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this but when I run "whereis java" I am still pointed to my Java 6 instalaton?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comes from the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Choosing_the_default_Java_to_use).

Comment: Thanks, I did this but when I run "whereis java" I am still pointed to my Java 6 instalaton?

Comment: What about `which java`?